# M Code in PQ Editor for Adding Workdays Minus Holidays

Tags: powerquery

I need M Code to create a new date column that is the result of: subtracting 70 Workdays minus Holidays from a column of dates. The below code works for workdays but will I need to subtract holidays as well. I currently have "Holidays" as a list minus weekends.

```
Code
(startdate as date, workingdays as number) => 
  let
    Source = List.Select(
      List.Dates(
        Date.AddDays(startdate, -7), 
        workingdays + 1 + Number.RoundUp(workingdays / 5, 0) * 2, 
        #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)
      ), 
      each List.Contains({1..5}, Date.DayOfWeek(_))
    ){workingdays - 1}
  in
    Source
```

I created a Query with the above function, then a Custom Column. it works to add days but when I put a (-) in the code it would not minus days. I also need to minus holidays.

Comment: Please post some sample data, including expected output.

Comment: For example, the first date in a PQ Editor column is 3/1/2024 and I would need to minus 70 workdays plus Holidays (from a created List of Holidays) from that date and the result would be in a New Column.  In standard Excel I would use the formula : Workday(A1,-70,Holidays!$B$1:$B$50), assuming the date was in A1, but in PQ Editor I need the M Code to reference the Holiday List but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Please do not add a comment.  Edit your question to provide sample input data  (formatted as text,  not an image) , and sample output data and explain how you get from input to output

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
let // find weekday, 70 days prior to findme, excluding listed holidays
holidays = {#date(2011,12,12),#date(2011,11,29),#date(2011,11,18)},
findme = #date (2011,12,31),
Last = List.Difference(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform( List.Dates(findme, 300, -#duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),each if Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday)>4 then null else _)),holidays){69}
in Last
```

Comment: Thank you. I got Token Identifier Expected at 70dayagodate

Comment: Sorry, small naming error on my part. Please retry

Comment: I missed our last responses. I tried this code by creating a Custom Column but it returned a column with a repeated date of 9/21/2011 in all rows.

Comment: And I assume you removed the findme line and replaced it with your date column, correct ?

Comment: I did  not. I am not as familiar with M Code  but I replaced those and that worked, but it is still only skipping weekends and not holidays. I named the list Holidays. I imagine I am missing something or is there anything else that needs to be replaced?

Comment: Sorry. Perhaps someone else can help you

Comment: Okay thank you for the help. The code is close just need it to pickup all the holidays.